# SQL joins with mulitple where conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have one table that looks like this:

```
[Jobs]
+-----+-------+---------+
+ ID  + Title +  Active +
+-----+-------+---------+
+ 1   + Admin +     0   +
+-----+-------+---------+
+ 2   + Mgr   +     1   +
+-----+-------+---------+
+ 3   + Emp   +     0   +
+-----+-------+---------+

[JobsTxt]
+-------+-------+---------+
+ JobID + Text  +  Type   +
+-------+-------+---------+
+ 1     + test  +   1     +
+-------+-------+---------+
+ 1     + test2 +   1     +
+-------+-------+---------+
+ 1     + test3 +   2     +
+-------+-------+---------+
+ 3     + test  +   1     +
+-------+-------+---------+
```

I want to write a query that gives me the Text entries from the JobsTxt table that have Type= 1 and Active=0 in the Jobs table, where JobsTxt.JobID = Jobs.ID

So it'd be something like:

```
Select [JobsTxt].Text from [JobsText] left join [Jobs] on [JobsTxt].JobId = [Jobs].ID where [JobsTxt].Type = 1 and [Jobs].Active = 0
```

I'm very new to joins and queries like this, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Best practices would be to select from Jobs and left or inner join JobsTxt

Comment: query looks fine.. I would change `left join [Jobs]`  to `inner join [Jobs]` if you have to check the `Active` flag for each row.. just for readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EXISTS are good if you dont require a JOIN, meaning you only need fields from one of the tables.

```
SELECT jt.Text
FROM   [JobsText] jt
WHERE  jt.Type = 1 
       AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   [Jobs] j
        WHERE  j.ID = jt.JobID
               AND j.Active = 0
    );
```

Comment: Great, I believe this is what I needed.  I thought I should use a join, but EXISTS is what I needed.  I wasn't aware of that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse, I am not allowed to comment directly on your question. So, let me just put it here, even as I think this may not qualify as an answer.

To me, your SQL statement looks perfectly okay and should deliver what you described. Maybe you could help us out and give some information on the SQL dialect involved (i.e., what database system you are running and what version)?

**edit:**
it seems you do have a typo:

```
[...] from [JobsText] [...]
                 ↑ - should there be an 'e'?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of below query:

```
    DECLARE @Jobs TABLE (ID INT, Title VARCHAR(10), Active BIT )
    INSERT INTO @Jobs VALUES
    (1,'Admin',0),
    (2,'Mgr',1),
    (3,'Emp',0)


    DECLARE @Jobtxt TABLE ( JobID INT, [Text] VARCHAR(10), [Type] INT)
    INSERT INTO @Jobtxt VALUES
    (1,'test',1),
    (1,'test2',1),
    (1,'test3',2),
    (3,'test',1)


    SELECT 
        Jt.JobID,Jt.[Text] 
    FROM 
        @Jobtxt Jt INNER JOIN @Jobs J ON Jt.JobID = J.ID
    WHERE 
        J.Active = 0 AND Jt.[Type] =1
```